# Microsoft Ax Dynamics Turorial

Tags: crm, erp, ax

i like to change my profession from DOT NET developer to Microsoft Dynamics Ax,

Queries:

1. will it be helpful with current it Scope
2. Where would i learn, please suggest some proper tutorials and i have tried some but its not up to mark

Pl help me out, thanks n advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some pretty good training books for AX. Try searching Development I, II, or III for Dynamics Ax. You can usually find a pdf version of these as they are typically available from the partner source portal and end up other places.

Comment: thanks , is there any trail software to work out..?

Comment: I don't believe there's any trial software that's available on demand. Typically if you contact a Dynamics Sales Rep they may give you access to trial versions. Either the software with trial licenses or might even just spin up an Azure server with it installed on it for you.

Comment: Thanks kevin , you into ms dynamics ?, can i have your skype id, so that i can clarify my doubts before entering into it, buzz me at gouthamarul23@gmail.com,